# Can I change which server my Minecraft skin goes to? (If yes, how?)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Before anybody closes this... **I am not referring to the current method of obtaining skins.**

## How do I change the old skin? (Obtained through Method 1)

I know the upload box in your [Minecraft Profile page](http://minecraft.net/profile) changes the result for the new (second) result, but is there any way to sync or at least change the old (first) method?

As you can see, the skins on both URLs (for the same user) are different. (not in the sense that one is the newer 64x64 format and the other is still 64x32 but they are both completely different skins)
*One is some sort of futuristic armor guy in a dwarven armor, while another is a... Er.. [this](http://spiralknights.com/).*

**Link 1:** http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/aytimothy.png
**Link 2:** http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/46e54b38ca489583f5f3e69cd0f25c50adcf29253fc5169dc6abafdc4770

Can I change the old skin (obtained through the first method) with baked textures (anything on the armor layers goes onto the actual skin layer) so that it'll appear the same in pre-r1.3 versions?

---

In Minecraft, there are currently two ways of obtaining skins.
*The following examples are with my own skin.*

#### The old Method:

1. Find the username's skin through the Amazon CDN links or via the game site.

   ```
   GET http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/aytimothy.png
   ```

   or:

   ```
   GET http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/aytimothy.png
   ```

And that's it. (Literally)
**Note:** The `skins.minecraft.net` link has been updated to retrieve the skin from `textures.minecraft.net` (second link).

#### The new Method:

1. Find the username's UUID from the Mojang API.

   ```
   POST https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/aytimothy
   ```

   Which results in something like this:

   ```
   {
    "id": "29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119",
    "name": "aytimothy"
   }
   ```
2. Find the Base64 string that contains the skin/cape texture link.

   ```
   GET https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119
   ```

   Which results in something like this:

   ```
   {
    "id": "29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119",
    "name": "aytimothy",
    "properties":[
        {
        "name": "textures",
        "value": "eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0MzM1ODA2NTQwNDUsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjI5YzkxYmQwNTM4YjRmYjZiMjEyZTIzOTNmYWZmMTE5IiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJheXRpbW90aHkiLCJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDZlNTRiMzhjYTQ4OTU4M2Y1ZjNlNjljZDBmMjVjNTBhZGNmMjkyNTNmYzUxNjlkYzZhYmFmZGM0NzcwIn19fQ=="
        }]
   }
   ```
3. Decode the Base64 compressed string...

   ```
    eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0MzM1ODAxNzg4MzUsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjI5YzkxYmQwNTM4YjRmYjZiMjEyZTIzOTNmYWZmMTE5IiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJheXRpbW90aHkiLCJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDZlNTRiMzhjYTQ4OTU4M2Y1ZjNlNjljZDBmMjVjNTBhZGNmMjkyNTNmYzUxNjlkYzZhYmFmZGM0NzcwIn19fQ==
   ```

   Which means:

   ```
   {"timestamp":1433580178835,"profileId":"29c91bd0538b4fb6b212e2393faff119","profileName":"aytimothy","textures":{"SKIN":{"url":"http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/46e54b38ca489583f5f3e69cd0f25c50adcf29253fc5169dc6abafdc4770"}}}
   ```

This results in a final URL of http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/46e54b38ca489583f5f3e69cd0f25c50adcf29253fc5169dc6abafdc4770

Comment: I don't believe there is.... I sincerely hope there is though :P

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, depends on what version you have. Please tell me and I might know =3

Comment: @AmyFreeman, I know I can change my skin for anything-after-1.3 versions of Minecraft through the profile. But I was wondering if there was any way to do so to the old skin on the Amazon server that the anything-before-1.3 versions of Minecraft use.

Comment: just a quick question, you have 2 skins? one which is used with older versions before 'alex' was released, one in the old 'steve' format? and you want to edit the steve skin?

Comment: No, you can't. The code wouldn't be able to transfer your skin as you switched. You'd have to quit the game, and then re-start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Support Pages](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/979200-minecraft-skins):

> If you are playing version 1.3 or earlier, skin changes will not be reflected in-game.

Additionally, a message is shown near the skin upload field:

> Note: Skin changes in Minecraft version 1.7.9 and future versions should happen immediately. If you are playing version 1.7.8 or an earlier version, skin changes may take up to an hour to be applied. **If you are playing version 1.3 or earlier, skin changes will not be reflected in-game.**

(emphasis mine)

This basically means you can't change your pre-1.3 skin anymore.

Comment: For bonus points, do you know why? (Or explain/theorise?)

Comment: @aytimothy Why would Mojang have any reason to support 3-year-old (as of the time this question was asked) Minecraft versions?

Comment: @pppery I think I was asking for the technical "why" not?

Answer (score 0):

to change your minecraft skin (only works with 1.7+), you will need to go to mojang, enter your username and password, go to profile, save your skin image, click on add new skin, click the picture you save the skin then open minecraft! (BTW, so sorry i got confused at what you were trying to say but this method can help! :D)