# My Minecraft skin has been turned inside out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft skin is completely black except I still  have my old skins hood.and when I look inside myself I can see my skin. It is really weird here's a screenie
it is the best picture I could get.
[image: its in hypixel]

Comment: What is your [tag:minecraft] username? Can you provide us with your original skin image so that we can compare? If you do not have a copy to upload, you can download it off the skin servers with the [method outlined in this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/222444/75275). Any other observations?

Answer (score 4):

Your skin has a solid black outer layer. I'd guess that this happened because you saved it with a tool that doesn't support transparency (e.g: MS Paint).

[image: legopower30's current skin]

If you want to modify skins, you'll need to use a tool such as [Paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) which does support transparency.

Here's your skin with the black/white parts cut out, which should work:

[image: legopower30's skin fixed]